# MATH: Using sine w/frame count to dictate emission

Tags: animation, node-editor, mathematics, emission

[image]I have 2 scenes at 35 fps (yes, non-standard)
Scene "L" 175 frames:
5 sections of 35 frame each
Emission should turn on/off once during each 35 frame interval per object
There are 5 objects, they should flash in sequence

Scene "R" 245 frames:
7 sections of 35 frame each
Emission pulse once every 35
There 7 objects, they should flash in sequence

How I have it setup now in material:
+[Value node] = #frame + {frame spacing integer} -->>

+[MAP RANGE node] = Min 0; Max {total frames}; Min 0, Max = ***{???}*** -->>

+[MATH; SINE node] -->>

+[Principled BSDF; Emission]

Not sure what to put into {???} to get the desired results. I got Scene "L" to work using 35 but that doesn't translate to the Scene "R". The {scene spacing integer} does enough to make the rings in Scene "L" work but not really sure how it does.

Answer (score 3):

First, no need to use map range. Second, sine produce result from -1 to 1, so either trim negative values or move them by 1 (or remap like in the image below). Lastly, one sin cycle is 2pi (not 1.0). So to get the right cycle, divide value on count of frames and multiply by 2pi. If you want to start with the lowest point of sine wave, you should offset the value by half of pi.

[image]

Multiplier is `1/35*pi*2`

Addend is `-pi/2`

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks!!